# Use VBA to change filters on all pivot tables

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook with several hundred pivot tables. All of the pivot tables are using data from an SSAS cube. The tables are all basically structured the same way, but they have different "location" filters. What I want to do is have code that will change a "date" filter for all of the tables so that I do not need to manually update each of the tables. (No, slicers will not work for me). I'm very much new to using VBA, so I'm a bit at a loss. I found this code, which I thought might work, but all it does for me is clear the filters on the other tables...possibly because I'm pulling from an external source? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
On Error Resume Next
Dim wsMain As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ptMain As PivotTable
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pfMain As PivotField
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim bMI As Boolean

On Error Resume Next
Set wsMain = ActiveSheet
Set ptMain = Target

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each pfMain In ptMain.PageFields
bMI = pfMain.EnableMultiplePageItems
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
        If ws.Name & "_" & pt <> wsMain.Name & "_" & ptMain Then
            pt.ManualUpdate = True
            Set pf = pt.PivotFields(pfMain.Name)
                    bMI = pfMain.EnableMultiplePageItems
                    With pf
                        .ClearAllFilters
                        Select Case bMI
                            Case False
                                .CurrentPage = pfMain.CurrentPage.Value
                            Case True
                                .CurrentPage = "(All)"
                                For Each pi In pfMain.PivotItems
                                    .PivotItems(pi.Name).Visible = pi.Visible
                                Next pi
                                .EnableMultiplePageItems = bMI
                        End Select
                    End With
                    bMI = False

            Set pf = Nothing
            pt.ManualUpdate = False
        End If
    Next pt
Next ws
Next pfMain

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: So you need to refresh all the pivots to refresh by the date column you mentioned above???

Comment: for example, the date filter in all of the pivot tables would need to change from "Jan 1" to "Mar 3"

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try the following code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
On Error Resume Next
Dim wsMain As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ptMain As PivotTable
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pfMain As PivotField`enter code here`
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem

Dim pvfilter as string
On Error Resume Next
Set wsMain = ActiveSheet
Set ptMain = Target

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
pvfilter = InputBox("Enter the pivot filter string")
For Each pfMain In ptMain.PageFields

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
        If ws.Name & "_" & pt <> wsMain.Name & "_" & ptMain Then
            pt.ManualUpdate = True
            Set pf = pt.PivotFields(pfMain.Name)

                    With pf
                        .ClearAllFilters
                                .CurrentPage = pvfilter
                    End With


            Set pf = Nothing
            pt.ManualUpdate = False
        End If
    Next pt
Next ws
Next pfMain

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What belongs in "enter code here"? I tried leaving code as is and it presents an error. If I eliminate that bit and change a filter then it provides me with an input box, but it doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: Actually, running this code is having the same effect as the code I tried earlier. It clears the filter on the other tables

Comment: Could the problem be that the data source has the information within a hierarchy? When I go to the filter, it has something like "+Date" which I need to click before I have the option to specify the date. How do I specify the full path of the data?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you update this code as subroutine and run this macro whenever you need to apply a filter to pivot tables instead of directly using the code in pivot update event.

```
Sub Test()
On Error Resume Next
Dim wsMain As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ptMain As PivotTable
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pfMain As PivotField
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem

Dim pvfilter As String
On Error Resume Next
Set wsMain = ActiveSheet
Set ptMain = Target

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
pvfilter = InputBox("Enter the pivot filter string")
For Each pfMain In ptMain.PageFields

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
        If ws.Name & "_" & pt <> wsMain.Name & "_" & ptMain Then
            pt.ManualUpdate = True
            Set pf = pt.PivotFields(pfMain.Name)

                    With pf
                        .ClearAllFilters
                                .CurrentPage = pvfilter
                    End With


            Set pf = Nothing
            pt.ManualUpdate = False
        End If
    Next pt
Next ws
Next pfMain

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```